Are there good tools for counting details during a conversation?
Wushu mechanics assume counting narrative details for building dice pools. Players describe details, but it's the Director (aka GM) who counts them:

I would give Jeremy 3 dice for the narration above
...
A generous Director might divide it up even more

What are good methods for counting details in real time, both in online and offline games? It should be something unobtrusive (so as not to disrupt the other person's narrative), but clear and visual (in order to convey the information in a handy way).
What I've tried and was not very happy with:

Handing dice for building the dice pool. Not very handy, since there're two dice types (yin and yang).
Using poker chips or other counters. Messes up with Threat counters.
Counting aloud. Distracts from the conversation.
Just ignore this part and let players count for themselves. Works fine(ish), but it's not very clear when it's time to get to the rolling.

Speculative answers are possible, but personal experience will be preferred.

For in-person games: hand gestures.
The director visibly uses their fingers to count the details they recognize in the player's narration. For example:

I throw my arms open wide (director shows 1 finger) and an automatic pistol pops into each hand from spring-loaded holsters up my sleeves  (director raises a second finger). I hold the triggers down (3 fingers), spin down onto one knee (4 fingers), and spray them with lead (5 fingers)!


Players can give the floor to each other. What do you do when another player steps into the narration?

I came here to post this - I do the exact same thing, and it worked great during our 33-episode Wushu adventure. As for yielding floor, I just remembered the first player's count and started counting the other player's pool when they jumped in. It helped that our max pool sizes were only ever 5-6. @enkryptor

@enkryptor As long as there are only two people involved, you can two hands. If it gets more, you have to memorize who got how many dice. It's mostly a communication tool between player and director about how many details the director recognized without interrupting the narration.

@enkryptor There are also some easy finger counting methods to let you go past 5 - for example, retracting fingers in order. I always start with thumb, so thumb down = 6, and all-but-pinky down = 9.

Experienced players count their own Details.
As stated in comments, I've run an approximately 100 hour Wushu campaign. By the end of it, I estimate that 75% of the players were counting the details for me, as they spoke them, because they had fully internalized the method.
So, as a bit of a frame challenge, if you plan on an extended game, that is, you won't end up needing tools.

I guess that this works well with groups who spent a lot of time playing Wushu together. But for groups who just assembled, this might not work that well because the players don't have an intuition yet about what the director would accept as a "detail".

@Philipp Yes, I attempted to clarify that my answer was only applicable to that context.
